# Error while installing rvm ruby package on mac

Tags: ruby, react-native, rvm

The error given below is getting while installing the rvm ruby on mac.

Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /Users/mac/.rvm/log/1666243305_ruby-2.5.5/make.log

please help me to find out. Thank you!

Comment: Please share what's in `/Users/mac/.rvm/log/1666243305_ruby-2.5.5/make.log`

Comment: Usually when this happens to me, I have some libraries missing...